# issue with loading event via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I start calendar with code below:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    slotDuration: '00:15:00', /* If we want to split day time each 15minutes */
    minTime: '00:00:00',
    maxTime: '24:00:00',
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
   // events: allevents,
    events: '/app/Http/Controllers/api/calendarController.php?action=getEvents&calendar_id=<?php echo $calendarid; ?>',
    editable: true,
    eventStartEditable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
})
```

The controller which I am calling will return json similar to:

```
 [
    {"id":1,"title":"Test","start":"7-02-2017 15:36","end":"7-02-2017 15:36","className":null,"description":null},
    {"id":2,"title":"test","start":"6-02-2017 11:00","end":"6-02-2017 12:00","className":null,"description":null},
    {"id":3,"title":"asdadsadasd","start":"30-01-2017 12:00","end":"30-01-2017 12:00","className":"bg-green","description":"asdasdasas"},
    {"id":4,"title":"sadsadsa","start":"31-01-2017 12:00","end":"31-01-2017 13:00","className":"bg-blue","description":"asasds"}
]
```

The problem is that for some reason data are not shown on the calendar?

Thanks for any answers.

---

Extra note: I am running FullCalendar v2.0.0-beta2

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: nothing in the javascript console

Comment: Can I see the actual json that is returned when you go to that url?

Comment: The json in the main message is what is returned; except on the web it would be without line breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it myself with the data you gave me and they are showing up just in the wrong place. You think you are putting the date in `D/MM/YYYY` format but full calendar is reading it as `M/DD/YYYY`. Change the format to `MM/DD/YYYY` and it works fine. The JSON you posted would look like this

```
[
  {"id":1,"title":"Test","start":"02-07-2017 15:36","end":"02-07-2017 15:36","className":null,"description":null},
  {"id":2,"title":"test","start":"02-06-2017 11:00","end":"02-06-2017 12:00","className":null,"description":null},
  {"id":3,"title":"asdadsadasd","start":"01-30-2017 12:00","end":"01-30-2017 12:00","className":"bg-green","description":"asdasdasas"},
  {"id":4,"title":"sadsadsa","start":"01-31-2017 12:00","end":"01-31-2017 13:00","className":"bg-blue","description":"asasds"}
]
```

Comment: yes, it was due to dates... I ended up using standard mysql datetime and fullcalendar dealt with it.

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help